# How do I ensure a complete reading of a log after the process that writes it ends on Linux?

Tags: linux

This is under Ubuntu 20.04.
There's a script that appends to a file via shell redirection.
I want to read that file after the script's process has ended and all data has been written.
I'm using pgrep to check when the script ends (I have carefully checked that this check works).
I have noted that the file may not be fully written even if the process ended.

Because of what I have read, this can happen because of buffering. A side question would be: can this actually happen or am I misunderstanding something?

I'm thinking on using lsof/inotifywait/a loop with fuser to await the file closing. Is this the right wait to manage this situations?

What I don't really understand is: if the process that opened the file exited, who will show as the file "opener" on lsof/inotifywait/fuser output?

Comment: Is the file fully written _eventually_? Otherwise, there's a bug in the program that writes the file.

Comment: Yes, it is. If I just wait, the file will eventually have the output written on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're worried about the file not having been written to disk due to buffering and it's in a process where you don't have the file descriptor, you can force the system to write them to disk with the `sync <file>` command or `sync` function in `unistd.h`.

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know about sync. Thank you!

Comment: Note that "The writing, although scheduled, is not necessarily complete upon return from sync()." https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sync.html

Comment: That's true for the posix specification, but from the linux man page `According to the standard specification (e.g., POSIX.1-2001), sync() schedules the writes, but may return  before the actual writing is done.  However Linux waits for I/O completions` so you should be good for Ubuntu

Comment: You are right! Should have checked the actual implementation doc. Thanks!